# XPath statement not executed in IDE

Tags: testing, selenium

i faced a problem while replaying a script created for yahoomail page.The XPath statement to enter value in the "To" text field , is not working.Following are the XPath statements i used.

At the first try i  used

```
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>to</td>
 <td>mgtest@ymail.com</td>
</tr>
```

Second try was this statement

```
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>//div[@id= 'toid']/textarea[@id= 'to'][@name= 'to']</td>
 <td>mgtest@ymail.com</td>
</tr>
```

Third try was this

```
<tr>
 <td>typeKeysAndWait</td>
 <td>//div[@ id= 'composebox']/div[@id= 'toid']/textarea[@id= 'to'][@name= 'to']</td>
 <td>mgtest@ymail.com</td>
</tr>
```

The result was like

*`[error] Element //div[@ id= 'composebox']/div[@id= 'toid']/textarea[@id= 'to'][@name= 'to'] not found`*

similar result was obtained in the previous attempts.
Later when i tried

```
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>css=textarea.txtfield</td>
 <td>mgtest@ymail.com</td>
</tr>
```

mail id was entered into the text field ,and the script worked perfectly.what might be the reason.Any thoughts.?

I am adding the XPath statements

```
<div id="composepage">
<div id="composebox" class="roundcorner">
<div id="errorContainer"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="defFromAddress" value="mgtest@ymail.com"/>
  <div class="fields row">
  </div>
  <div id="toid" class="row">
  <label id="compose_to" for="to">
  </label>
  <textarea id="to" class="txtfield" name="to" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" style="overflow: hidden; height: 19px;"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written invalid xpath query.

It should be

`//div[@ id='composebox']/div[@id='toid']/textarea[@id='to' and @name='to']`

Answer (score 0):

The `<textarea>` has an id attribute, which should be unique, so your first locator of simply `to` should work. It's possible that the element is not present or visible when your selenium command executes. I would recommend the following:

```
waitForVisible | id=to | 60000
type | id=to | mgtest@ymail.com
```

If your elements have unique ids, and you need to use XPath, you only need to be relative to the closest element with an id attribute.

Comment: Thank you Dave,The text area got selected , but , no data was typed into it.But the following statement worked.

waitForVisible | id=to | 60000                                      

type | //textarea[@id='to'| mgtest@ymail.com